# How to expose the emmc from target board to host pc

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I have a custom am335x based board which I am able to boot via uart booting. I have developed a small initramfs that boots buildroot standard image and mounts the emmc and my script runs fdisk commands at boot to partition the emmc. I would like to know

1. How to make the target board  mount the emmc on my pc via the usb so that I can transfer the actual files on to the emmc.
2. What services / tools do I need to put on the target.
3. Can I do it via buildroot itself?
4. Is there a way to make fastboot work on the linux on the target board?

Comment: You have to look at `usb-gadget` framework with specific function (in your case mass storage). Perhaps a good start point is https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/gadget/intro.html